# Authenticating in Email HTML Form

Tags: html, forms, flask, html-email, okta

I'm building a web service for internal use and one feature I would like to implement is having users be able to fill out HTML forms and submit from email so that they don't necessarily have to go to the web page to use its functionality. The problem is that the web page requires authentication via nginx so a simple redirect won't work. Accessing the email account requires authenticating into Okta which is also the same creds that will get you into nginx, so is it possible to somehow pass along that information to the form?

The web page is running on flask, just in case that's important.

Answer (score 0):

In short the answer is no. In most modern day mailing services such as gmail the mail will be counted as spam because you are trying to gather "sensitive" information(even if its something as simple as a name)

Trying to gather information through email is a security risk and you should do so only through your secure server